# Are questions on framing and matting prints on topic?

Tags: discussion

I'm a total twit when it comes to matting and framing prints and drawings, so I would like to ask many questions about proportions, colors, spacing.   Visually pleasing design follows common principles whether it's inside the frame or is the frame.  Seems like framing would be a fair topic for Graphics Design.

But I don't see any questions here on these things. Is this on topic?  Is there another SE for framing?

Answer (score 2):

To me, including framing here would be a real stretch. I understand where you are coming from because I've worked with framers and framing departments in larger companies in the past, but there was a pretty wide gap between what they did and what we did; we never consulted each other on anything.

If there isn't a site on Area 51 for framing, you are free to propose one if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Use of proportion and color in visually framing an image -- using matting or just white space -- probably would not be out of place in Photography.SE, assuming that at the professional photographers there exhibit their images. Faux matting is quite common, done in Photoshop, particularly for a collection of images, a portfolio, or a book. The principles that apply to photographs are equally applicable to prints and drawings.

If you were designing a coffee-table book and wanted to know what colors, proportions, etc. to use to "mat" the images on the page, such questions would fall well within the scope of GD. (I'm not saying you should simply pretend that's the case, but I also won't tell on you if you do. Promise!)